# Edit WP theme to allow for upload of logo

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

Ive got a WP theme that generates the logo / title by the name of the blog / site as specified under the settings > general tab.

What id like to do is change this so a user can insert a custom logo - png / jpg / gif ect.

Im quite conformable with sql, php and html / css but ive not used them in the context of wordpress before.

I know i could do this by just editing the theme and setting it to `<?= //logo path.png ?>` but i was wandering how i can change this so a non technical user could update it as part of the CMS under appearance > theme options

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of good plugin which allow you to upload logo from Wordpress Backend

1) http://wordpress.org/plugins/logo-manager/

2) http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-logo-plugin/

Just install one of it, and File upload button would be there in Backend.